# How to disable sorting rows without effecting table header resize events in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I'm trying to disable the sorting event of jQuery DataTable, i found some ways to do that but all is resulting to also disable column resizing.

My Html:

```
<div id="Grid">
    <table cellspacing="0" id="" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="sorting_disabled">Name</th>
                <th class="sorting_disabled">Number</th>
                <th class="sorting_disabled">Email</th>
                <th class="sorting_disabled"></th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Ali</td>
                <td>+961231</td>
                <td>alikleit@@gmail.com</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>saeed</td>
                <td>+123</td>
                <td>123@@gmail.com</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    var table = $('#Grid table').DataTable({
        //"aoColumnDefs": [{
        //    "bSortable": false,
        //    "aTargets": ["sorting_disabled"]
        //}], // also results in disabling column resize
        "ordering": false,
        'dom': 'Rte',
    });

});
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the table will size to it's contents. Try adding the autoWidth option = false.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


var table = $('#Grid table').DataTable({
    //"aoColumnDefs": [{
    //    "bSortable": false,
    //    "aTargets": ["sorting_disabled"]
    //}], // also results in disabling column resize
    "ordering": false,
    "autoWidth": false,
    'dom': 'Rte',
});
```

});

Comment: autowidth is used to calculate the width it has nothing to do with resizing the column by the user. i tried adding but still no luck